# How Can i Access values from .aspx page to .aspx.cs page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have code something like this.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Submit", "Confirm()", true);
```

Confirm is the JavaScript function in .aspx page. I want to catch the "true" or "False" value returned based on the Click performed on the Confirm window to my code behind(aspx.cs) page.

Do we have a solution for this?

Comment: Either you can use AJAX to handle this kind of scenario, or else you can have a hidden field and change the value of the hidden field in the Confirm() function and after submitting access it as POST parameters in the aspx.cs. Btw, do you want the aspx.cs page to get the confirm value in real time or after a post back?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%=Method() %>
```

Would this help?

Comment: Jason, this would not work.  Code found in the angle brackets is evaluated by the ASP engine on the web-server.  Javascript is executed on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field in ur .aspx page and on submit assign proper value to
the hidden field from jQuery or javascript

```
function submit()
{ 
    var value="sumting"; 
    $("input[id$=hdnFldValue]").val(value);
}
```

In the Code behind u will get the hidden field value
now u can perform ur desired task.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: it throws javaScript runtime error. I guess something its problem with "$("input[id$=hdnFldValue]").val(value)" synatx..

Comment: Its a jQuery code to use the above code u need to add jQuery Reference to your page

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?') == false) return false;", true)==true

Answer (score 0):

i tried this way to do it

```
function a()
{
  document.getElementById('<%=h1.ClientID)%>').value=0;
}
```

Comment: please share some explanation for your answer as well.I don't think your code answers the question.